# Sound problem with XEN in SUSE Enterprise 11 64 bit

Tags: linux, audio, xen, suse

sound card is working well inside SuSE and everything is ok there. But when I install Windows 7 or XP inside Xen Virtualization software, I can't use sound card and Windows is unable to find any sound hardware.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use Xen, but the documentation for the configuration file for the guest mentions the following line which is initially commented-out:

> audio=1

Other documentation, [Configuration file for unmodified VMX guests](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_virtualization/xen_3.0_user_guide/linux_virualization_xen_user_67.html), mentions another parameter:

> **enable-audio**
>  Enable audio support. This is under development.

You might check what values have these variables, but I don't really like the words "under development".

Comment: ok then ... it's under development !!!??? :(